# Dump in PyYaml as utf-8

Tags: python, utf-8, pyyaml

I'm trying to load a bunch of utf-8 encoded strings and dump them again with PyYaml. This is the code for loading/dumping:

```
lang_yml = yaml.load(codecs.open(lang + ".yml.old", "r", "utf-8"))
test_file_path = lang + '.yml'
stream = file(test_file_path, 'w')
yaml.dump(lang_yml, stream,  default_flow_style=False, encoding=('utf-8'))
```

But a strings that start as "En arrière" ends up being saved as "En arri\xE8re".
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Found the answer myself. I just had to dump it with the argument

```
allow_unicode=True
```

Source: http://dpinte.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/pyaml-dump-option/